Creating a simple coroutine example without defining both coroutine and promise_type structs
I'm a great believer that difficult concepts should be taught from simple to complex.
I'm trying to create a minimal coroutine example to explain the concepts. I'm trying to show interleaved execution with voluntary scheduling.
This is what I have so far
#include <iostream>
#include <coroutine>
// Coroutine promise type
struct Coroutine {
    struct promise_type {
        Coroutine get_return_object() {
            return Coroutine{ std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this) };
        }
        std::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        void return_void() {}
        void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
    };

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;

    Coroutine(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h) : handle(h) {}
    ~Coroutine() {
        if (handle) handle.destroy();
    }

    void resume() const {
        handle.resume();
    }
};

// Coroutine function
Coroutine my_coroutine() {
    std::cout << "coroutine step 1" << std::endl;
    co_await std::suspend_always{};  // Suspend here and return control to main
    std::cout << "coroutine step 2" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "main step 1" << std::endl;
    Coroutine coro = my_coroutine();
    coro.resume();  // Resume the coroutine to the first suspension point
    std::cout << "main step 2" << std::endl;
    coro.resume();  // Resume the coroutine to completion
    return 0;
}

Is there any way to simplify this further?
Perhaps a default built in promise_type in c++23? ( not interested in external libs )
Note:
I will have a separate simple example with std::generator, but that will be a separate topic. Looking for pure coroutine await/yield/resume example on this one.

This is too simple, I am afraid. It lacks of proper copy and move semantics. Copy should be deleted, move should care about handle - see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/coroutine_handle

No, there is no default coroutine type. There are many different use cases for coroutines, and each needs a coroutine type tailored to that use case.
Your example doesn't return a value, and you resume it multiple times, but a coroutine that resumes with a move-only value should be resumable only once.
template<typename T>
struct task {
    struct promise_type {
        T value;
        std::exception_ptr exception;
        task get_return_object() {
            return task{ std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this) };
        }
        std::suspend_always initial_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        template<std::convertible_to<T> From>
        void return_value(From&& from) { value = std::forward<From>(from); }
        void unhandled_exception() { exception = std::current_exception(); }
    };

    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> handle;

    task(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h) : handle(h) {}
    ~task() {
        if (handle) handle.destroy();
    }

    T get() {
        while (!handle.done()) {
            handle.resume();
            if (handle.promise().exception) {
                std::rethrow_exception(handle.promise().exception);
            }
        }
        return std::move(handle.promise().value);
    }
};

An awaitable type that interacts with some outside system needs to do something with the handle it is passed in await_suspend, but the coroutine it is used in need not be resumable.
struct switch_to_new_thread
{
    std::jthread* p_out;
    bool await_ready() { return false; }
    void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> h)
    {
        std::jthread& out = *p_out;
        if (out.joinable())
            throw std::runtime_error("Output jthread parameter not empty");
        out = std::jthread([h] { h.resume(); });
    }
    void await_resume() {}
};

coro fire_and_forget() {
    // ...
    std::jthread& victim = get_some_thread();
    co_await switch_to_new_thread{ &victim };
    // ...
}

int main() {
    fire_and_forget();
}

